# How to add the new JSON from existing JSON file

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I searched here get few related posts found but not helpful. I created one json file it has some text i want to append some more json in that using javascript(JSON stored in locally).

I have `json file` like this:

```
{ "Home": [ "a", "b", "c" ] }
```

i want to include this text `"Log": 1`

want to achieve like this,

```
{ "Home": [ "a", "b", "c" ], "Log": 1 }
```

Now I have like this in my json file(currently i have but json format is not correct)

```
{ "Home": [ "a", "b", "c" ] } 
{ "Log": 1 }

$.getJSON('myfile.json', function(data) {
    alert("success");
}.error(function(data){
    alert(JSON.stringify(data));
});
```

this returns `parser error`. I know the JSON format is wrong. Please guide me to create a correct JSON format.

Comment: Can you show the code you use to write and append to the json file as this is the problem?

Comment: @LcLk ` var homeicons = {
      "Home" : g
    };` `var a = JSON.stringify(homeicons);`

Comment: `{ "Home": [ "a", "b", "c" ], "Log": 1 }`(a) or `[{ "Home": [ "a", "b", "c" ] } , { "Log": 1 }]`(b), you can't just append data to a json string and get a working json string. If you go with (b) you can achieve (a) with `var array = /* data from (b) */; var result = {}; $.extend.apply($, [{}] + array);`;

Comment: @Prusse please provide more detail..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to read your JSON, parse it into a JS object, edit the object, and convert back into JSON before writing:

assuming myfile.json contains:
    { "Home": [ "a", "b", "c" ] }

```
$.getJSON('myfile.json', function(data) {
    alert("success");
    obj = JSON.parse(data);
    obj.log = 1;
    writeJSON(JSON.stringify(obj));
}.error(function(data){
    alert(JSON.stringify(data));
});
```

and writeJSON will be something like:

```
function writeJSON(jsonString)
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'myfile.json',
        data: jsonString,
        success: function(data) { alert('write succesful!'); },
        contentType: "application/json",
        dataType: 'json'
    });
}
```

assuming that you are using a server which can both read and write via this endpoint.

Comment: the problem is i called my javascript file, in another script file using $.getScript...now the the script is not loaded....

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Can't you just update both scripts and try again? What server are you using anyway, I think there may be more problems here than meet the eye.

Comment: this `myfile.js` have the `$.getJson ` function ...when remove the `$getJson ` the js file is loaded...otherwise not loaded...

Comment: Can you add all of your code to a jsfiddle, or at least include it in the original question as a snippet? Not your entire project but the myFile.js, the file which loads it and the server which deals with the json request.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27173196/not-able-to-load-the-script-file-inside-another-script-file

Answer (score 4):

The error is in both versions of the JSON. You are missing the `"` at the *start* of the string `c`.

http://jsonlint.com/ will help you track down where errors in JSON occur.

As a rule of thumb, you should create JSON using a JSON serializer in a mature library and not by hand or string concatenation.

---

> Now i have like this in my json file

That's completely wrong. The code you had in "Now i want to achieve like this" was right (aside from the error mentioned above).

Comment: in jsonlint the following format is ok..{ "Home": [ "a", "b", "c" ], "Log": 1 }

Comment: @Anu — Yes, that's what I said.

Comment: @Anu — Like that! You just put that in the file!

Comment: i already have some json in file want to insert new json/values in that json..please see my post...

Comment: @Anu — That part of your post doesn't make sense. You're talking about JSON that is stored locally but you are accessing it remotely using HTTP.

Comment: It might have helped to mention phonegap from the outset. How you write to a file using phonegap is very specific. I don't know how off the top of my head. Try their API documentation.

Comment: i am able to write and read the json files in phonegap....my problem is how to combine existing json with new json...in javascript