# Not able to load the script file inside another script file

Tags: javascript, jquery

Not able to load the script file inside another script file when using `$.getJson();` inside the loaded script files.

Consider **fisrt.html**:

```
<script>
$.getScript("second.js",function(){
     // some code here
});
</script>
```

my second js file is like:
    second.js:

```
$.getJSON("somefile.json",function(){
});
```

When remove the `$.getJSON` from the **second.js** the files load perfectly without any problem.

How can I load the my json file with `$.getJSON`?

EDIT:

complte json calling:

```
$.getJSON('js/offline.json', function(data) {
            alert("success");

        }.error(function(data){
            alert(JSON.stringify(data));
        });
```

Comment: Are there any errors in the console?

Comment: @iliacholy nothing shows..

Comment: There's colon instead of a semicolon after `getJSON`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to use the promise and standard callback API at the same time. Here's what you want.

```
$.getJSON("js/offline.json")
  .done(function (data) {
    alert(data);
  })
  .fail(function (err) {
    alert(err);
  });
```

Comment: My code is correct https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/javascript-debugging

Comment: Yes your is correct one...Sorry for the delay to accept(went outside)...Thank you...

Comment: any idea bout this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27172383/how-to-add-the-new-json-from-existing-json-file#27172700

Answer (score 1):

You can try using the following function:

```
function loadScript(url, callback)
{
    // Adding the script tag to the head as suggested before
    var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.type = 'text/javascript';
    script.src = url;

    // Then bind the event to the callback function.
    // There are several events for cross browser compatibility.
    script.onreadystatechange = callback;
    script.onload = callback;

    // Fire the loading
    head.appendChild(script);
}
```

Also:
1. Remove the `:` in the second script to replace with `;`
2. make sure that `somefile.json` exists in the same directory.